# Trying to seperate OnClickListener() to another class

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create an onClickListener for another class, but there's a NullPointerException. I already tried to pass the value of context, but still, it didn't work. I don't know what value is null.

This is the class for ExternalOnClickListener

```
public class ExternalOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener{

private Context context;

public ExternalOnClickListener(Context c) {
    context = c;
}

public void setRowCol(Intent hardLevelIntent) {
    hardLevelIntent.putExtra("rowCount", 6);
    hardLevelIntent.putExtra("colCount", 6);
    hardLevelIntent.putExtra("difficulty", 3);
}

@SuppressLint("NonConstantResourceId")
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //Hard levels intent
    Intent hardLevelIntent = new Intent(context, GameActivity.class);
    setRowCol(hardLevelIntent);
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnBack:
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Level_Selection.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.btnHard1:
            hardLevelIntent.putExtra("hardStageCount", 1);
            context.startActivity(hardLevelIntent);
            break;
    }
}
```

}

And the btnEndless.onClickListener() here is trying to create an object for the external onClick. But there's a null pointer exception

```
public class Level_Selection extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageButton btnBack, btnEasy, btnAverage, btnHard, btnEndless;
ImageButton btnHard1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_level__selection);

    this.btnBack = findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
    this.btnEasy = findViewById(R.id.btnEasy);
    this.btnAverage = findViewById(R.id.btnAverage);
    this.btnHard = findViewById(R.id.btnHard);
    this.btnEndless = findViewById(R.id.btnEndless);
    this.btnHard1 = findViewById(R.id.btnHard1);

    btnBack.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Menu.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    });

    btnEasy.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Level_Easy.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    });

    btnAverage.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Level_Average.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    });

    btnHard.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Level_Hard.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    });

    btnEndless.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        btnHard1.setOnClickListener(new ExternalOnClickListener(getApplicationContext()));
        btnHard1.performClick();
    });

}
```

This is the error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.flip, PID: 10862
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at com.flip.Level_Selection.lambda$onCreate$4$Level_Selection(Level_Selection.java:59)
    at com.flip.-$$Lambda$Level_Selection$EhORL8AmJ4WhZjndwpPfbUXg1uA.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6312)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24811)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
```

I hope someone answers my question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check your XML. Your code looks fine.

Comment: There error is on line 59 of Level_Selection.

Comment: And also you actually don't need to pass the context in the constructor. You can do this as well.
`Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Level_Selection.class);v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
`

Comment: How do I know which line is 59?

Comment: Line 59:
btnHard1.setOnClickListener(new ExternalOnClickListener(getApplicationContext()));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try check btnHard1 value, is it null?
Make sure there is ImageButton with id 'btnHard1' in your activity_level__selection layout.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your R.layout.activity_level__selection, doesn't containt of button which you set click listener or has different id